# После переключения слайдов ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined at HTMLDivElement

Tags: javascript, слайдер

После переключения трёх слайдов появляется ошибка

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined at HTMLDivElement
```

HTML

```
 <div class="slider">
            <div class="slider_img">
                 <div class="slide slider_show">
                     <img src="img/slider_img_1.png" alt="shrimps">
                 </div>
                 <div  class="slide slide_hide">
                     <img src="img/slider_img_2.png" alt="dorada_fish">
                 </div>
                 <div class="slide slide_hide">
                     <img src="img/slider_img_3.png" alt="vodka">
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider_nav">
            <div class="slider_nav_prev">
                <img src="icons/slider_prev.png" alt="previous">
            </div>
            <div class="slider_nav_next">
                <img src="icons/slider_next.png" alt="next">
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
  const nextbtn = document.querySelector('.slider_nav_next'),
  prevbtn = document.querySelector('.slider_nav_prev'),
  sliderNav = document.querySelector('.slider_nav'),
  slide = document.querySelectorAll('.slide'),
  dot = [];
  let slideIndex = 1;


nextbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
if(slideIndex == slide.length) {
    slideIndex = 0;
} else {
    slideIndex++;
}
slide.forEach(item => {
    item.classList.add('slide_hide');
});

slide[slideIndex].classList.add('slide_show'); 
slide[slideIndex].classList.remove('slide_hide');

dot.forEach(dot => {
    dot.style.opacity = 0.5;
});
dot[slideIndex].style.opacity = 1;
});
```

Ошибка появляется на этих строках

```
slide[slideIndex].classList.add('slide_show'); 
slide[slideIndex].classList.remove('slide_hide');
```

Comment: «Ошибка  +/-1 индекса» будет преследовать вас всегда =) `if (slideIndex == slide.length - 1)`

Comment: сработало, спасибо!) дошло, надо же так ступить) не верится, что весь вечер провела пытаясь найти это=)